# How to solve following problem in topology involving relatively compact sets?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

For a subset $A$ of a topological space $X$, let $\hat{A}$ denote the union of set $A$ and all those connected components of $X\setminus A$ which are relatively compact in $X$. Then for every $A \subseteq X$,

1) $\hat{A}$ is compact. $\qquad$ 2. $\hat{A} = \hat{\hat{A}}$ $\qquad$ 3. $\hat{A}$ is connected. $\qquad$ 4. $\hat{A} = X$

I am confused in 2 and 3.

1) Incorrect. Take $A = (0,1)$ and $X = \mathbb{R}$. Then $X\setminus A = (-\infty, 0) \cup (1, \infty)$. Now $X\setminus A$ has two components and none is relatively compact, so here $\hat{A} = A$. Since $A$ is not compact, so $\hat{A}$ is not compact.

4) Take same $A$ as taken in $\underline{1}$ to make it incorrect. How to solve this further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $3$; This is not true for general topological space since it could be a disconnected space.
Let $X$={a,b,c,d,e} and $\tau=${$X,\emptyset,$ **{a}, {b,c,d,e},{a,c,d}, {c,d}** } and $A$=**{a,b,c,d,e}**.

Now that $X-A=\emptyset$ it follows that $Â=A$ but $A=X=${a}$\cup${b,c,d,e} which are open and disjoint.

For $2$ ;the first inclusion comes by definition.Conversely, calling **Â=E**,suppose that $Ê\nsubseteqÂ$ then there should be a compact and connected $K\subset X$ with $K\subset X-Â$ but $A\subset Â$ so $K\subset X-A$ and by definition $K\subset Â$,absurd.

Comment: But for $3$, are you sure that $\hat{A} = A$

Comment: what about component of $X-A$ given by $(1,2)$, it is relativley compact.

Comment: you're right i've mistaken the definition of relatively compact,sorry

Comment: i've edited it but if you find another mistake tell me so i can correct.

Comment: @ AHandsomeAlien Great thinking level. thanks